# .NET XmlSerializer : How to replace name of the xml tag?

Tags: .net, xmlserializer

For some data export, what we are doing is just serializing the .Net objects like a list or Collection using XmlSerializer. We use something like this:

```
public static bool WriteToXMLFile(string fullFileNameWithPath, Object obj, Type ObjectType)
        {
            TextWriter xr = null;
            try
            {
                XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(ObjectType);
                xr = new StreamWriter(fullFileNameWithPath);
                ser.Serialize(xr, obj);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                if(xr != null)
                    xr.Close();
            }
            return true;
        }
```

For a list of a type, the XML that is generated comes like the following segment:

```
<ArrayOfMyObjects>
    <MyObject>
    //content here
    </MyObject>
</ArrayOfMyObjects>
```

But the expectation on the other side (receiver of this file is something like this:

```
<MT_MyObjects>
    <MyObject>
    //content here
    </MyObject>
</MT_MyObjects>
```

So how can I change ArrayOfMyObjects to MT_MyObjects while serializing? I know it can be done using some Regx replacement also. But I wanted not to touch the output later.

**Update: The solution:**

I could solve the issue finally like this:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("MT_LoadProfile")]
public class LoadProfArray : List<LoadProfile>
{
    //....
}
```

Comment: Where is your class definition? Put a snippet. Also is it a list you try to serialise?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For serialising Arrays, you can define attributes which governs how an object is serialised. However if the object is a list, you need to create a class and inherit from it and then define the attributes:

```
[XmlRoot("DocumentTypes")]
public class DocumentTypeEntityCollection
{

    [XmlElement("Type")]
    public  List<DocumentTypeEntity> Items { get; set; }
}
```

This will create this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<DocumentTypes>
  <Type>
    <TypeID>7</TypeID>
   ....
```

Answer (score 3):

In your class, decorate the property with

```
[XmlArray("MT_MyObjects"), XmlArrayItem(typeof(MyObject))]
```

Comment: Can you please some example, I have tried, but yet to get success.

Answer (score 2):

Please Find The Example below:
/*Step1*/
The Dummy Class whose collection was to be serialised

```
[Serializable]
    public class MyObject
    {
        public string ChildObject1 { get; set; }
        public string ChildObject2 { get; set; }
        public MyObject(string childObject1, string childObject2)
        {
            ChildObject1 = childObject1;
            ChildObject2 = childObject2;
        }
        public MyObject()
        {

        }
    }
```

/*Step2*/
Create a List Collection and Apply The XMLRootElement

```
[XmlRoot("Test")]
    public class MyObjectCollection: List<MyObject>
    {

    }
```

/*Step3*/

Populate the MyObject Class with Data and serialise

```
MyObjectCollection lst = new MyObjectCollection();
            lst.Add(new MyObject("1", "a"));
            lst.Add(new MyObject("2", "b"));
            lst.Add(new MyObject("3", "c"));
            try
            {
                XMLFileAgent.WriteToXMLFile(@"C:\TestLog.xml", lst, lst.GetType());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
```